# Create a custom function to remove rows with specific conditions in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to create a custom function that can remove rows under certain conditions: For example, If I see that `col1` has two identical values `a` that are also present in `col2`, I intend to delete the row with `a` in `col1` and `b` in `col2` while remaining other rows.

Below is an example of how all my datafame look like:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "m", "m", "m", "m", "n", "q"),
                 col2 = c("a", "b", "m", "x", "y", "z", NA, "p"))
  col1 col2
1    a    a
2    a    b
3    m    m
4    m    x
5    m    y
6    m    z
7    n <NA>
8    q    p


My desired outcome
  col1 col2
1    a    a
2    m    m
3    n   <NA>
4    q    p
```

**I eddited my originl question**.
Any suggestions???

Comment: I am not able to match your explanation and the expected output that you have shown. One of the confusion is `I intend to delete the row containing both a and b values.` but you have row with `a` value in the output.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks alot. I editted my question. Sorry for confusing you!

Comment: Do you need something more than `filter(df, col1 == col2)`?

Comment: @r2evans I felt my question is so dump now, I confused myself with unnessary conditions. Yes, you are right, nothing more than that. However, since my dataset is huge, I was overthinking that it not just simple like that.

Comment: It's easy to spiral one's self away from simpler solutions, glad that's all it was.

Comment: @r2evans I just found a problem with my huge dataset and Im going to edit the question

Answer (score 1):

You could `group_by` on col1 and use a `filter` to check which values are equal to keep them like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  filter(col1 == col2)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#> # Groups:   col1 [2]
#>   col1  col2 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     a    
#> 2 m     m
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Why do you need `group_by`?

Comment: I just updated my example data format and also my explanation.